# How to run vue directive function?

Tags: vue.js

I have this vue 2 cli directive

```
directives: {
swipe: {
  inserted: function runme(el) {
  alert(el);
    },
  },
},
```

How can I run runme(obj) from methods or another directive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could factor out the common code into its own standalone method that could be called from anywhere:

```js
function swipeInserted(el, binding, vnode) {
  alert(el)
}

export default {
  directives: {
    swipe: {
      inserted: swipeInserted,
    },
    other: {
      inserted(el, binding, vnode) {
        swipeInserted(el, binding, vnode)

        // other code specific to this directive...
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    runInserted() {
      const el = {/*...*/}
      const binding = {/*...*/}
      const vnode = {/*...*/}
      swipeInserted(el, binding, vnode)
    }
  }
}
```